# A question on asymptotics of a sequence and that of corresponding series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

$\beta_n$ is a  sequence of positive real numbers.It is known that $\beta_n = O(1/n)$ and $\beta_n\ne o(1/n)$. What can we say about the series $$\sum_{k=0}^n \beta_k$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series may converge or diverge. Consider the examples

$$
\beta_n = \frac{1}{n}
$$

and

$$
\beta_n = \begin{cases}
2^{-n} & \text{if } n \neq 2^m \text{ for any } m \in \mathbb Z, \\
2^{-m} & \text{if } n = 2^m \text{ for some } m \in \mathbb Z.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I am not asking for convergence. I mean to know it has any particular asymptotics. Like $O(log(n))$.

Comment: It cannot converge

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju, the second example I gave in my answer converges.

Comment: Both co ditions ate simultaneous. It is O(1/n) and not o(1/n) at same time.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju, yes, I know that. The second example satisfies both conditions *and* converges.

Comment: looks like there is some  misconception about my notation or some misunderstanding. by $\beta_n \ne o(1/n)$ I intend $\beta_n$ does not decay faster than $1/n$. Let me know if anything wrong with my notation.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju, that is not very clear. The formal definition of $\beta_n = o(1/n)$ is $\lim_{n \to \infty} |n\beta_n| = 0$, so $\beta_n \neq o(1/n)$ means $\lim_{n \to \infty} |n\beta_n|$ doesn't exist or is $> 0$. This is equivalent to $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |n\beta_n| > 0$. For the second example of my answer, $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |n\beta_n| = 1$, so $\beta_n \neq o(1/n)$ and $\beta_n = O(1/n)$.

Comment: Please see this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: According to above link, your second example is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for  the answer Antonio

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju Could you clarify what you mean by "your second example is not valid"?

Comment: I thought (1/2)^n decays rapidly than 1/n. I caught between exponential and hypebolic.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju, but $(1/2)^n$ does decay more rapidly than $1/n$. The point is that $\beta_n$ is not equal to $(1/2)^n$ for all $n$, only for some.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju, maybe writing it this way would make it clearer: $$\beta_n = \begin{cases} 1/n & \text{if } n = 2^{m},\, m \in \mathbb Z \\ (1/2)^n & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Hah i got it now. This makes more clear to understand.